# how to build a real chat application in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chat, long-polling, private-pub

I'm building a web app which has chatting as a feature. I've decided to use the private pub gem for this. But in private pub you have to subscribe to a channel with this code snippet

```
<%= subscribe_to "/messages/new" %>
```

Now i want this code to be executed on two client ( the one who initiated the chat request and the one who is receiving the chat request) and that too with a unique channel so that there is only a pair of clients subscribed to a channel. I can make the chat initiater subscribe to a channel but how do i make the 'intended' client at the other end subscribe to that particular channel?


Should i keep a field for javascript in the DB and have the client execute it when the field is not null?..ofcourse i would have to use long polling in that case.

Comment: I think it should be JS function with interval 3-10 sec, which checks if this user is invited to chat

Comment: So that means long polling right??..if i want to use long polling should i bother using private pub..i mean why not just building the entire chat app with polling

Comment: Akshay- private-pub is based on Faye, which is already doing long polling.

Comment: You may want to consider using a third party service such as pusher.com to handle the realtime communication. No need reinventing the wheel, unless of course this a learning exercise.